# Getting Symfony2 to work on shared hosting using only .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony, shared-hosting

I've been searching for this for 4 days now and couldn't find a working solution.
I want to make Symfony2 work on shared hosting without access to command line or *httpd.conf* (there's no way to set virtual host). All I can do, is just edit *.htaccess* files. In my web root directory I also have some other projects (like forum). The directory structure is:

```
public_html
 |-forum
 |-ox
 '-Symfony
    |-app
    |-bin
    <...>
```

I can make it work both in dev ant prod environments (routing works well), BUT it doesn't load any assets (js, css, images). In error log there's always the same:

```
request.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /bundles/acmedemo/images/welcome-demo.gif" (uncaught exception)
```

Same happens if asset is loaded not from *bundles*, but also in *twig* as:

```
{{ asset('css/main.css') }}
```

Then it ends up with

```
request.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /css/main.css" (uncaught exception)
```

My *.htaccess* in public_html is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# DEV ENVIRONMENT #
RewriteRule ^$ Symfony/web/app_dev.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Symfony/web/app_dev.php/$1 [QSA,L]

# PROD ENVIRONMENT #
#RewriteRule ^$ Symfony/web/app.php [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Symfony/web/app.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any suggestions how to make things right?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem. After digging around the code I found following solution.

Create a class named `PathPackage.php` in `src/Vendor/YourBundle/Templating/Asset` folder with following code.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\YourBundle\Templating\Asset;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\Asset\PathPackage as BasePathPackage;

class PathPackage extends BasePathPackage
{
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param Request $request The current request
     * @param string  $version The version
     * @param string  $format  The version format
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request, $version = null, $format = null)
    {
        parent::__construct("/Symfony", $version, $format);
    }
}
```

Then in your `app/config/config.yml` add the following parameter.

```
parameters:
  // ...
  templating.asset.path_package.class: Vendor\YourBundle\Templating\Asset\PathPackage
```

Now it will append `/Symfony` to the asset url parameter.

To summarize `asset` twig function calls [getUrl](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Templating/Asset/PathPackage.php#L45) method to determine the url. Which is extended by [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/Asset/PathPackage.php) class. Object of the class is passed as argument during [templating.helper.assets](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/templating_php.xml#L37) service creation. Luckily PathPackage class is [configurable](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/templating_php.xml#L19). So solution was possible :).

Comment: If I just add a line to config.yml, then I get an error: _InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "templating.asset.path_package.class" (in ...app\config\config.yml). Looked for namespace "templating.asset.path_package.class", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "assetic", "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_security_extra", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"_ Isn't such parameters confugured just in XML? And if so, I couldn't figure out how to do it :(

Comment: You have to add it in parameters section. Edited my comment.

Comment: Then I get _ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Cronus\TplBundle\Templating\Asset\PathPackage::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, none given, called in ...app\AppKernel.php on line 21 and defined in ...src\Cronus\TplBundle\Templating\Asset\PathPackage.php line 17_ I think I'll just keep all CSS files and images in _web/bundles..._ and use _asset('bundles/...')_ cause as I see there's no simple way to do it and I have no time (after a week of searching)

Answer (score 1):

Do `php app/console assets:install ./web` locally, and upload the content of web folder  your remote shared hosting.

Comment: How can I do it in xampp running on Win7? Googled for it, but no result.

Comment: OK.. I've got it working at last, but when I execute a command, I get _Could not open input file: app/console_

Comment: @CRONUS Are you in Symfony folder?

Comment: OK. It installs assets from bundles, but it's still the same with assets which are used globally - like from \app\Resources\css\. These are not installed anywhere after executing the command. I also couldn't find any documentation about this - maybe it's not possible and these globally used css files or images should be in every bundle? If so, then it worked for me from the start :) But I think if it's correctly loaded without htaccess from app.php/css/... then it should be also available to use with rewrite.

Comment: I just found out that it works normally if i just use asset like <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/cronustitle/css/core.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all" /> BUT it doesn't work if I use {% stylesheets ... %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />{% endstylesheets %}